# Any idea about this error ? I am using react native

Tags: react-native

"export 'Card' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
5 |   return (
6 |

> 7 |       
> |       ^
> 8 |
> 9 |       
> 10 |

Comment: We need some Code to help you out.

Comment: Can you post some code to make us in context?